# getchar and scanf buffer issues. getchar not storing the correct value

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'm pretty new to programming and I understand that scanf() has some quirks to it. Namely, when it detects characters that don't match up with its conversion specifiers, it immediately returns and puts the offending characters back into a buffer in order to be read by another scanf() call or by some other function which can access the buffer.
However, I'm doing a book exercise and the code behavior is odd.

```
    float total = 0, operand = 0;
    char operator = 0;

    printf("Enter an expression: ");

    scanf("%f ", &total);

    while ((operator = getchar()) != '\n') {
        scanf("%f", &operand);
        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                total += operand;
                break;
            case '-':
                total -= operand;
                break;
            case '*':
                total *= operand;
                break;
            case '/':
                total /= operand;
                break;
        }
        printf("Value of operator: %c\n", operator);
        printf("Operand: %f\n", operand);
    }

    printf("Value of expression: %f\n", total);
```

The two printf calls are for testing. An input of: "1 + 5 + 9\n" results in:

```
Value of operator: +
Operand: 5.000000
Value of operator:  
Operand: 5.000000
Value of operator:  
Operand: 9.000000
Value of expression: 6.000000
```

So, the program seems to go like this:
scanf() reads 1 into 'total', pairs the space after it with the space in the format string, encounters the '+', then puts it back into the buffer and returns.

Then:

Loop 1 - getchar() reads the leftover '+' and places it into 'operator'. scanf() reads 5, encounters the space, puts it back into the buffer, and returns.

Loop 2 - getchar() reads the leftover ' ', and places it into 'operator' scanf() encounters '+' and immediately returns and places it back into the buffer.

Here's where things don't align with my understanding. At the start of loop 3, getchar() should encounter the '+' and store it into 'operator'. Instead, it's skipped completely, and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Try debugging statement-by-statement to see what is hapenning.

Comment: Always check the return value of function call, specifically the library ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first loop the input buffer holds " + 9\n"

So `getchar` will read the space and the input buffer then holds "+ 9\n"

Then `scanf("%f", &operand);` will first read the `+` which is valid for a float. So it continues and reads the next space which isn't valid for float after a `+` so the conversion fails. The space is left in the input buffer but the already read `+` can't go back so it is lost.

This is described in the standard (quoting N1570):

> An input item is read from the stream, unless the specification includes an n specifier. An
> input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
> any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence. 285)
> The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.

Where note 285 says:

> 285. fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream.

So in short:

When scanning a `+` followed by a space (i.e. "+ ") using a numeric conversion specifier will result in a matching failure and the `+` will be silently removed from the input.

A simple solution in your case could be:

```
while ((operator = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (operator == ' ') continue;
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I forgot that %f could read prefixes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the returned value of `scanf` as it returns the number of format specifiers it has been able to read.  You still need to know if there has a `float` been input or not.  In either case you need to do different things... perhaps to signal a syntax error, if the order of operators and numbers is not appropiate.

Think also the possibility or scanning `+3.5` as a float or as an operator `+` followed by an unsigned floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

skip spaces here: `while ((operator = nextchar()) != '\n')` instead of `getchar()`

where `nextchar()` can be something like

```
int nextchar(void) {
    int ch;
    do ch = getchar(); while (ch == ' '); // assume '\n' shows up before EOF
    return ch;
}
```